# Access to the path is denied with multiple instances of application

Tags: asp-classic, access-denied

I am using ASP (not .NET)

From time to time I get error `Access to path **** is denied` When it tries to modify the log file i have. All required permissions for this are set, and yet from time to time it denies access.

Since I have multiple instances of the application running at the same time, my speculation is that 2 or more instances try to modify the log file at the same time and 1 or more of the instances gets rejected (to prevent corruption of file?) and errors out.

Any suggestions about this would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: That is probably what is happening.  Try setting a different log file for each instance you have running.

Comment: With the current logging system that's not possible. The only way to solve this, I guess by proper exception handling.

Comment: can you show you code?